# How to deploy npm project to gh-pages

Tags: github, npm, github-pages, package.json

I'm trying to deploy a website to gh-pages using npm. I'm using blain HTML and CSS and asynchronous javascript. I haven't used any SPA framework (react or angular).
I'm currently using lite server for development purposes and gh-pages package.

I'm trying to deploy the src folder using the following command 
`npm run deploy`

it fails because the build script is not specified.
my question is what should I write in the build script?

when I try to run `npm run deploy` it displays the following error

```
'src' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! AmrAhmed@1.0.0 build: `src`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the AmrAhmed@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-30T11_30_29_824Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! AmrAhmed@1.0.0 predeploy: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the AmrAhmed@1.0.0 predeploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Amr\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-30T11_30_29_869Z-debug.log
```

in similar projects using react, the build script has the following `react-scripts build`

this is my package.json file

```json
{
    "name": "AmrAhmed",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "truffle.js",
    "directories": {
        "test": "test"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "lite-server",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "src",
        "predeploy": "npm run build",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d src"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "gh-pages": "^3.0.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
    }
}
```

[election folder content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhOir.png)

[src folder content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp9CH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that you don't need the build script or the pre-deploy script. they are unnecessary to be used, since my website is static, I can navigate directly to the build folder and it will work fine.

I have modified the config.json file to be as in the following

```json
{
    "name": "AmrAhmed",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "truffle.js",
    "directories": {
        "test": "test"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "lite-server",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d src"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "gh-pages": "^3.0.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
    }
}
```

run the command 
`npm run build`

and it will be deployed to Github pages.

Answer (score 0):

you should also add "homepage":"https://yourGithub.github.io/your-repo" above "name" in the package.json